# Inject component in angular dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to create generic dialog and inject different component into when is necessary.

In example I have dialog and injected component `first-component`:

```
<dialog>
 <first-component></first-component>
</dialog>
```

Or if I want I can reuse dialog and inject another component:

```
<dialog>
 <second-component></second-component>
</dialog>
```

Can we dod this in angular material?

Comment: According to the [Angular Material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api), you can pass a Component to the open function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. If you need it in an own UI-library, you  probably are looking for `<ng-content>`, a placeholder-angular-HTML-tag, that can be replaced by any Content(-Child), which is passed from the parent-component down the hierarchy. See as reference: https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild

Or if you are in a domain component and have a fixed number of possible content, you can use `<child-component *ngIf="condition; else #otherComponent">`or for more than two possibilities `*ngSwitchCase`

Alternatively, if you want the content to be controlled by the URL, you can use `<router-outlet>`; see https://angular.io/guide/router